# replace char from string for turkish configuration

Tags: javascript

I had a chat function in my site and this function did not display Turkish characters properly. So that, i wrote this function below but it returns nothing. Where did it go wrong? Text gets comments as string.

```
function FindAndReplaceAll(text) 
{
  var normal = new Array("Ä±","Å?","Ã¼","Ã§","Ã¶","Ä?","ÅŸ","Ã‡","Ä°","ÄŸ","Åž","Ã–","Ãœ","Ä±","Å?","Ã§","Ã¶","Ä?","ÅŸ","Ã‡","Ä°","ÄŸ","Åž","Ã–","Ãœ","Ã¼","ÄŸ");
  var turkish = new Array("ı","ş","ü","ç","ö","ğ","ş","Ç","i","ğ","Ş","Ö","Ü","ı", "ş", "ç", "ö", "ğ", "ş", "Ç", "i", "ğ", "Ş", "Ö", "Ü", "ü", "ğ");

  for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) 
  {
    for(var j = 0; j < 27;j++)
        {
            if(text.charAt(i) == normal[j])
            {
                text.charAt(i) = turkish[j];    
            }

        }
  }


  return text;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Your chat application probably doesn't have the correct encoding defined. You shouldn't have to do this at all. Check here for the `<meta>` tag you should add in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889001/turkish-characters-problem

Comment: Do not try to replace some chars, but fix the underlying character encoding issue.

Comment: Probably, you are right. Because if i did "text = 'ş'", it displays correcty as it is (ş). In here, I was trying to solve the problem indirectly.

Comment: But if i did "text = 'ş'", every comments became "ş":)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/f9u5S/)

Check it out..

```
   function FindAndReplaceAll(text) 
    {
  var normal = new Array("Ä±","Å?","Ã¼","Ã§","Ã¶","Ä?","ÅŸ","Ã‡","Ä°","ÄŸ","Åž","Ã–","Ãœ","Ä±","Å?","Ã§","Ã¶","Ä?","ÅŸ","Ã‡","Ä°","ÄŸ","Åž","Ã–","Ãœ","Ã¼","ÄŸ");
  var turkish = new Array("ı","ş","ü","ç","ö","ğ","ş","Ç","i","ğ","Ş","Ö","Ü","ı", "ş", "ç", "ö", "ğ", "ş", "Ç", "i", "ğ", "Ş", "Ö", "Ü", "ü", "ğ");

  for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i+=2) 
  {
    for(var j = 0; j < 27;j++)
        {
            if((text.charAt(i)+text.charAt(i+1)) == normal[j])
            {

               text= text.replace((text.charAt(i)+text.charAt(i+1)), turkish[j]);    
            }

        }
  }


  return text;
}
document.write(FindAndReplaceAll("Ä± Å? Ã¶"))
​
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this extension

```
public static string ReplaceToTurkishChar(this string input)
{
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
            return input;

        input = input
            //.Replace("&#305;", "ı").Replace("&#304;", "İ")
            .Replace("&Uuml;", "Ü").Replace("&uuml;", "ü")
            .Replace("&Ouml;", "Ö").Replace("&ouml;", "ö")
            //.Replace("&#286;", "Ğ").Replace("&#287;", "ğ")
            //.Replace("&#350;", "Ş").Replace("&#351;", "ş")
            .Replace("&Ccedil;", "Ç").Replace("&ccedil;", "ç");


        input = input
            .Replace("&#305;", "ı").Replace("&#304;", "İ")
            .Replace("&#220;", "Ü").Replace("&#252;", "ü")
            .Replace("&#214;", "Ö").Replace("&#246;", "ö")
            .Replace("&#286;", "Ğ").Replace("&#287;", "ğ")
            .Replace("&#350;", "Ş").Replace("&#351;", "ş")
            .Replace("&#199;", "Ç").Replace("&#231;", "ç");


        input = input
            .Replace("Ä±", "ı").Replace("Ä°", "İ")
            .Replace("Ã¼", "ü").Replace("Ãœ", "Ü")
            .Replace("Ã–", "Ö").Replace("Ã¶", "ö")
            .Replace("ÄŸ", "ğ").Replace("Ä?", "Ğ")
            .Replace("ÅŸ", "ş").Replace("Åž", "Ş")
            .Replace("Ã‡", "Ç").Replace("Ã§", "ç");



        input = input
            .Replace("\u0131", "ı").Replace("\u0130", "İ")
            .Replace("\u00FC", "ü").Replace("\u00DC", "Ü")
            .Replace("\u00F6", "ö").Replace("\u00D6", "Ö")
            .Replace("\u011F", "ğ").Replace("\u011E", "Ğ")
            .Replace("\u015F", "ş").Replace("\u015E", "Ş")
            .Replace("\u00E7", "ç").Replace("\u00C7", "Ç");

        return input;
}
```